# How to assign panda group data to a multi-index Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

## Aim

I have an initial data frame that looks like this:

```
   Serial No.  Data One  Data Two
0          01  0.258625  0.667996
1          01  0.192356  0.723055
2          01  0.738066  0.266488
3          01  0.374525  0.059664
4          01  0.193977  0.104213
5          01  0.213749  0.366608
⁞
49         05  0.948550  0.823888
```

I want to rearrange it into a multi-index data frame with columns of data type and serial number:

```
Data        Data One                  Data Two                
Serial No.        01  02  03  04  05        01  02  03  04  05
```

## Code

To generate and fill the multi-index Data Frame I've written a small block of code:

```
serial_numbers = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05"]
headings = ["Serial No.", "Data One", "Data Two"]
arrays = [[], []]
for ii, heading in enumerate(headings[1:]):
    arrays[0] += [heading]*len(serial_numbers)
    arrays[1] += serial_numbers

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(*arrays)), names=["Data", "Serial No."])

group = random_data.groupby(headings[0])
data = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((len(group.get_group(serial_numbers[0])), len(index))), columns=index)
for heading in headings[1:]:
    for serial_number in serial_numbers:
        data.loc[:, (heading, serial_number)] = group.get_group(serial_number).loc[:, heading]
```

## Problem

The above code creates a Data Frame where the first serial number of each data type is filled with values and the rest are NaNs:

```
Data        Data One                  Data Two                
Serial No.        01  02  03  04  05        01  02  03  04  05
0           0.258625 NaN NaN NaN NaN  0.667996 NaN NaN NaN NaN
1           0.192356 NaN NaN NaN NaN  0.723055 NaN NaN NaN NaN
2           0.738066 NaN NaN NaN NaN  0.266488 NaN NaN NaN NaN
3           0.374525 NaN NaN NaN NaN  0.059664 NaN NaN NaN NaN
4           0.193977 NaN NaN NaN NaN  0.104213 NaN NaN NaN NaN
5           0.213749 NaN NaN NaN NaN  0.366608 NaN NaN NaN NaN
6           0.829126 NaN NaN NaN NaN  0.972882 NaN NaN NaN NaN
7           0.494763 NaN NaN NaN NaN  0.482118 NaN NaN NaN NaN
8           0.024283 NaN NaN NaN NaN  0.538428 NaN NaN NaN NaN
9           0.700613 NaN NaN NaN NaN  0.067831 NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Why does this work for the first serial number of each data type but not others?

## Appendix

In the real world the input data comes from a CSV and pandas.read_csv but for the purpose of this question I've used numpy to generate random data and some other code to structure it.

```
serial_no_col = []
for serial_number in serial_numbers:
    for ii in range(10):
        serial_no_col.append(serial_number)
random_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(50, 3), columns=headings)
random_data.loc[:, "Serial No."] = serial_no_col
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for new indices created by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
print (df)
   Serial No.  Data One  Data Two
0          01  0.258625  0.667996
1          01  0.192356  0.723055
2          02  0.738066  0.266488
3          02  0.374525  0.059664
4          03  0.193977  0.104213
5          03  0.213749  0.366608
49         05  0.948550  0.823888

df = df.set_index([df.groupby('Serial No.').cumcount(), 'Serial No.']).unstack()
print (df)
            Data One                               Data Two            \
Serial No.        01        02        03       05        01        02   
0           0.258625  0.738066  0.193977  0.94855  0.667996  0.266488   
1           0.192356  0.374525  0.213749      NaN  0.723055  0.059664   


Serial No.        03        05  
0           0.104213  0.823888  
1           0.366608       NaN
```